# Error en un "Hola Mundo" usando Slim Framework

Tags: php7, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, slim

¿Como se hace el "Hola Mundo" en una instalación de SLIM?, he instalado el proyecto de la siguiente manera:

1. `composer require slim/slim:"4.*"`
2. `composer require slim/psr7`
3. configuro el apache en ***public/.htaccess*** con lo siguiente:

   `RewriteEngine On`

   `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

   `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

   `RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]`

4. en mi archivo ***public/index.php*** coloco:

```
<?php
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = AppFactory::create();

$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello world!");
    return $response;
});

$app->run();
```

y al momento de hacer correr el Hola Mundo en el navegador con la url `http://localhost/proyectoblog/public/` me sale este error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Slim\Exception\HttpNotFoundException: Not found. in 
C:\laragon\www\proyectoblog\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware.php:93 Stack trace: #0 
C:\laragon\www\proyectoblog\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Routing\RouteRunner.php(72): 
Slim\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->performRouting(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) #1 
C:\laragon\www\proyectoblog\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(81): 
Slim\Routing\RouteRunner->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) #2 
C:\laragon\www\proyectoblog\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(215): Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) #3 C:\laragon\www\proyectoblog\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(199): 
Slim\App->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) #4 C:\laragon\www\proyectoblog\public\index.php(14): 
Slim\App->run() #5 {main} thrown in 
C:\laragon\www\proyectoblog\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware.php on line 93
```

Sin embargo cuando uso host virtuales con el comando `php -S localhost:8080 -t public public/index.php` si me muestra el Hola Mundo.

la cuestion es que necesito desarrollar el proyecto depurando con las url `http://localhost/proyectoblog/public/*` como lo vengo haciendo con php puro y laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontre la respuesta, basicamente no es necesario tener configurado en el local el ***.htaccess*** y despues de la linea `$app = AppFactory::create();` tuve que agregar lo siguiente:

```
$app->setBasePath("/proyectoblog/public");
```

Haciendo eso conseguí hacer el hola mundo con la url `http://localhost/proyectoblog/public/`